# Using find and xargs how can I stop execution on errors without crapping out

Tags: bash, shell

In my script I have the following 3 commands

Basically what it is trying to do is:

- create a symlink to a certain bunch of files based on their filenames, in a temp directory.
- change the name of the symlink to match the current date
- move the symlinks from a temp directory to their proper location

-

```
find . -type f -name "*${regex}-*" -exec ln -s {} "${DataTempPath}/"{} \;
find "$DataTempPath" -type l | sed -e "p;s/A[0-9]*/A${today}/" | xargs -n2 mv
mv $DataTempPath/* $DataSetPath
```

This will be inserted as a cron job to run every 15 mins, which is not a problem when the source directory contains valid data.
However when it doesn't contain any files I get errors on the second find command and the mv command

What I want I guess is a way of not executing the last two lines of the script if the first one does not create any new links

Comment: What error do you get from the second command?

Comment: mv: missing file operand

I am guess because the p in sed doesn't have anything to print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU `xargs` supports a `--no-run-if-empty` parameter that, to quote the documentation "If the standard input is completely empty, do not run the command. By default, the command is run once even if there is no input".
This should help avoid the `xargs` error (assuming you are running GNU `xargs`)

Answer (score 0):

check the status of the command:

```
find . -type f -name "*${regex}-*" -exec ln -s {} "${DataTempPath}/"{} \;
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then 
 find "$DataTempPath" -type l | sed -e "p;s/A[0-9]*/A${today}/" | xargs -n2 mv
 mv $DataTempPath/* $DataSetPath
fi
```

Comment: Nope, because the first find command doesn't fail, it just doesn't create any links, so therefore the exit code will always be 0

Comment: You specifically said in your question is that you want to perform the 2nd two lines if the first "fails". If it doesn't fail but you get 0 links created you could create a counter for your conditional statement.

Comment: I'll rephrase my original question, thanks for pointing that out to me